# Why can I call function which is not exported in sub-shell?

Tags: bash

I am learning bash. In my current understanding, I need to export function to use it in sub-shell. However, I can call a function which is not exported in sub-shell. I would like to know why or how non-exported function works in sub-shell. The test code is following,

file name : level1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
function level_1_func {
  echo "function 1: $1, PID=${BASHPID}"
}
```

file name : level0.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# *** If you don't load level1.sh before this function or script,
# *** level_1_func in this function causes an error of "command not found"
function level0_func {
  echo "function 0: $1, PID=${BASHPID}"
  level_1_func "inside level0_func"
}
```

top.sh

```
source "./level0.sh"

# *** Error in level0_func : "level_1_func: command not found."
# *** It is because level1.sh has not been loaded.
level0_func "in the current shell"

# *** Here it loads level1.sh. After this lines,
# *** it can call level_1_func even in sub-shell.
# *** (definition of function is exported automatically?)
source "./level1.sh"

out_puts="$(level0_func "in the sub shell")"
echo "${out_puts}"
```

Output of "bash top.sh" is following

```
function 0: in the current shell, PID=7575
./level0.sh: line 7: level_1_func: command not found
function 0: in the sub shell, PID=7577
function 1: inside level0_func, PID=7577
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not just the case with functions, but with everything else in the environment, including shell options, and even local variables.

For example:

```
 3.2: ~$ foo=42
 3.2: ~$ set|grep foo
 foo=42
 3.2: ~$ echo $(set|grep foo)
 foo=42
 3.2: ~$ bash -c set|grep foo
 3.2: ~$
```

Here is an example using a shell option:

```
3.2: ~$ set -o nounset
3.2: ~$ echo $(set -o|grep nounset)
nounset on
3.2: ~$ bash -c 'set -o|grep nounset'
nounset         off
```

The term "sub-shell" is overused, often inaccurately.  When you create a "true" sub-shell then bash makes a copy of the current process, so *everything* is copied (a `fork` action).  When you create a new process it basically destroys (an `exec` type action) anything that is not in the environment block, i.e. exported (other things are also retained from the original process, such as the user and group id, current directory, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for answering. I agree that it is better to discriminates two types of sub-shell, fork type and exec type, as you say. They are much clearer.

Comment: I would say a sub-shell is the `fork` action.  The `fork/exec` action is just running another process with its own program.  It is a child process but it might not be a shell.

Answer (score 4):

A subshell was invoked by the command substitution, but this subshell has the same context as the current shell. You need to invoke `bash` explicitly to create a new context.

```
out_puts="$(bash -c level0_func level0_func "in the sub shell")"
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried to find an instruction of "context" in bash manual. But I could not find it. Could you tell me where I can get the instruction of it?

Comment: I don't think there's any formal construct by that name; it simply refers to all the internal structures of the bash process.

Comment: Thank you again. I found a sentence in bash manual : "Functions may be exported so that subshells automatically have them defined with the -f option to the export builtin."  I suppose the sub-shell in the sentence means shell generated by explicit way in your example, but not one generated by command substitution. Is it the only case that I need to care of exporting function to sub-shell?

Comment: Yes. Direct execution in both command substitution and explicit subshell invocation (`(...)`) use existing definitions.